# UITableViewCell image anchored to the top

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am working with a UITable view with custom elements inside and I cannot get the pictures to stay in the location I placed then originally.

I am just following the tutorial from this website [Team tree house](https://teamtreehouse.com/library/build-a-diary-app-using-core-data/custom-uitableviewcell/customizing-table-view-cell-appearance)

This is how my design looks and how it's coming out int he simulator. Note that I am not using Autolayout because the guy in the video said we should not.

[image: Current status]

I have tried changing the project to use Autolayout and adding the constrains but that is not working either.

I added some custom code to make sure the controls stays in place but nothing.

This is what my code looks like.

**EntryListTableViewController.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    EntryCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    DiaryEntry *entry = [self.fetchResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell configureCellItemProperties];
    [cell configureCellForEntry:entry];
    [cell fixImage];

    return cell;
}
```

**EntryCell.m (only relevant methods)**

```
+ (CGFloat) heightForEntry: (DiaryEntry *) entry {

    const CGFloat topMargin = 35.0f;
    const CGFloat bottomMargin = 95.0f;
    const CGFloat minHeight = 106.0f;

    //The actual size of the label devided by 2 otherwise is not going to get it right.
    const CGFloat originalLabelWidth = 202.0f;


    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(originalLabelWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    NSStringDrawingOptions options = (NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading | NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin);
    UIFont *font = [UIFont defaultFontMedium];
    NSDictionary <NSString *, id> *attributes = @{NSAttachmentAttributeName: font};

    CGRect boundingBox = [entry.body boundingRectWithSize:constraint options:options attributes:attributes context:nil];


    return MAX(minHeight, (CGRectGetHeight(boundingBox) + topMargin + bottomMargin));

}

- (void) configureCellItemProperties {


    [self.dateLabel setFont:[UIFont defaultFontBoldMedium]];
    self.dateLabel.textColor = [UIColor portgoreColor];


    [self.bodyLabel setFont:[UIFont defaultFontMedium]];
    self.bodyLabel.textColor = [UIColor portgoreColor];
    [self.bodyLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [self sizeToFit];


    [self.locationLabel setFont:[UIFont defaultFontMedium]];
    self.locationLabel.textColor = [UIColor silverColor];

}

- (void) configureCellForEntry: (DiaryEntry *)entry {

    self.bodyLabel.text = entry.body;
    self.locationLabel.text = entry.location;

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter defaultWeekMonthDayYear];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:entry.date];
    self.dateLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];


    if (entry.image) {
        self.mainImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:entry.image];
    }else {
        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_noimage"];
    }


    if (entry.mood == DiaryEntryMoodGood) {
        self.moodImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_happy"];
    } else if (entry.mood == DiaryEntryMoodAverage){
        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_average"];
    } else if (entry.mood == DiaryEntryMoodBad) {
        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_bad"];
    }

}

- (void) fixImage {

    CGRect contentBounds = self.contentView.bounds;
    CGRect imageFrame = self.imageView.frame;

    imageFrame.origin.x = contentBounds.origin.x + 8;
    imageFrame.origin.y = contentBounds.origin.y;

    self.imageView.frame = imageFrame;

}
```

Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to kick yourself.

In

```
if (entry.image) {
    self.mainImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:entry.image];
}else {
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_noimage"];
}
```

you're setting the cell's `imageView` image, rather than `mainImageView`'s image in your `else` statement.

You have the same bug when setting your `moodImageView`'s image too.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You are a hero! Man how did you notice that ? I have been trying to solve this since yesterday. :)